# Convert "+" as an evaluation operator

Tags: c#

I want To do something like this: have a string "5+5" and when I convert it to integer, expected output want to be 10, but I get runtime error.
Would appreciate your opinion.

Comment: You'll need to implement (or find implementation) of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm.

Comment: _"...but I get runtime error"_ - what error?

Comment: To "calculate the string", you can try [Reverse Polish notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation) via `stack`.

Comment: I will recommend reading https://medium.com/@toptensoftware/writing-a-simple-math-expression-engine-in-c-d414de18d4ce

Comment: Question as asked is duplicate of many "parse math expression in C#" questions. Based on comment you left on an answer what is asked here and what you want are somewhat different things. If you really want "sum of integers separated by +" - [edit] question accordingly, otherwise do nothing here and for future questions demonstrate the effort (ideally with [MCVE]) rather than just "get error".

Comment: You can use `new DataTable.Compute("5+5")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `.Split()` string by `+`, Convert it to integer and Calculate `.Sum()`

```
   var result = "5+5".Split('+').Select(int.Parse).Sum();
```

[.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KmgxGp)